# What are the negative impacts of increasing fwrite BUFSIZE with setbuf/setvbuf?

Tags: c++, c

I know writing to secondary memory is an expansive operation.

Let's supose one calls `fwrite()` 10 times. It does not mean 10 writes to disk will be done. Depending on the OS, the calls will be buffered, in a buffer with `BUFSIZE` size (In my OS, 8192 bytes) and then when the buffer is full the whole buffer will be write at once.

I also know it's possible to force disk writing 10 times by using `fflush()` after each fwrite() call.

Also, I've came across functions such as `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()` which allow customizing the buffering.

My question is, what are the negative impacts of increasing the buffer size? Being naive, it seems that a big buffer would drasticly decrease secondary memory access. At the same time, 8129 bytes doesn't seem very big compared to my ram/stack size, so there must be a reason it's "small"

Comment: The main negative impact is that it delays writing the data, which may lead to data loss if the program crashes before the buffer gets flushed.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @ChrisDodd! If you would like to post your point as an answer I would mark it as accepted

Comment: Data lost would be one negative thing. If there is another program reading from that file, there would be another negative thing

Comment: @nluizsoliveira The details are implementation dependent.  "In my OS, 8192 bytes" --> `BUFSIZE` is not an OS issue, but a compiler one.  The compiler choice is influenced by the OS, yet the compiler has the ultimate choice.  In the end, customized buffer size performance improvement is not only complier dependent, but OS and user data set dependent. Beware of micro-optimization.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the points @SeverinPappadeux and chux - Reinstate Monica!

Comment: If you are writing 10 butters consider using writev() instead (if you cannot do the single `write()`).  Now you get the benefit of fewer kernel calls for the cost discussed above but with increased flexibility.

Comment: You could also ask the question if there will be a measurable benefit from increasing the buffer size. Have you tried?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think it's more accurate to call it a "C runtime implementation issue".  For example, changing `BUFSIZE` in `/usr/include/stdio.h` on a Linux system isn't going to change the default size of the buffer used by a `FILE *` stream created from an `fopen()` call.  That default value is set when libc is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Write() does not necessarily write the contents to disk.   Most OSes provide some sort of cache, thus write() commits the buffer to this cache and the disk may be updated quite a bit later, if at all.
After write(), subsequent reads() of the same file/pipe will find the data you have provided; thus the cache is coherent.  This is an important difference between the shared system file cache, and the per-program caches maintained by stdio.

The buffer (bufsiz()) used by stdio (putc, printf, fwrite) primarily aligns and chunks accumulated requests into efficiently sized units for I/O.   Guessing at bufsize's may affect performance in either way, but realize that the default for your system was likely chosen for a good reason.